# NetCore3.0 in serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, serverless

Anyone here knows how to set `dotnetcore3.0` as a runtime for [serverless framework](https://github.com/serverless/serverless)? I've looked up `Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport` but I'm just not sure how to apply this for serverless.

I'm currently using this [setup](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-core-3-0-on-lambda-with-aws-lambdas-custom-runtime/).

But if possible I'd like to use serverless because IMO it's much more flexible.

Thanks

Comment: Since i do not want to give you a link only answer  i am putting it as a comment . This should answer your question https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-core-3-0-on-lambda-with-aws-lambdas-custom-runtime/

Comment: I've already looked through that, the one I'm wondering about is how to use it with the serverless framework. Thanks though

Comment: Yes...this is the way to go...

Comment: I'm sorry, am I missing something here. That thing that you sent me was my existing setup. But I want to use the serverless framework, https://github.com/serverless/serverless to manage everything instead. Because there's much more tools available with serverless. The problem I'm having is that serverless only supports up to 2.1 currently, so i'm looking for a workaround

Comment: So i think you need to update the question..make it more explicit and precise..